# Bluetooth radio device is not available

Tags: windows-7, bluetooth

I reinstalled my Windows 7 operating system, and have since been unable to detect my Logitech m555b bluetooth mouse.

*Here is some info about my system:*

- I have have a working connection with a bluetooth printer.
- I have a message in the "My Bluetooth" section of explorer stating "Bluetooth radio device is not available".
- The Device Manager indicates that the Generic Bluetooth radio is working correctly.
- The bluetooth "F12" switch is on.  Mouse batteries are new and the right way around.
- I'm presuming that I need a bluetooth driver which is non generic.
- The computer is a Clevo P150HMx (the version with the GTX485 GPU) with the default WLAN / bluetooth combo card manufactured by Realtek (I think it's a Realtek RTL8188CE card).  I think I have the drivers installed, but I still get the generic driver in the Device Manager.
  I'm confused.  Please help, I'm going mad on the touchpad.
  (Thanks for the touchup wizlog)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all the correct Logitech software installed. They can be found [here](http://www.logitech.com/en-au/428/5747) in the downloads tab.

Comment: Thanks Wizlog, I have that installed already.  I've also tried uninstalling and reinstalling it.  No difference.  Thanks for the fixup for my post too :)

Comment: @Mike No problem, I'm glad to help.  Have you tried restarting your computer after you install the Logitech software?  (Also, this may sound really basic, but make sure that the batteries for the remote are installed and work.)

Comment: Yep, the power button is wearing out. Light on mouse is flashing (ie it's searching). Am going to reinstall the Realtek driver (again).  Will advise.

Comment: If you can connect to your bluetooth printer, then you don't need to worry about bluetooth drivers for your computer.

Answer (score 0):

Ah ok thanks. I've come to the conclusion my mouse has succumbed to ownerhaskids syndrome.  Not sure that there's an inexpensive cure for that which won't get me life in gaol.  The mouse will not make itself known to other computers either.  I'm off to look for a wired mouse.  Thanks for the assistance wizlog, much appreciated.  Mike

Comment: hm. don't forget to select this as the correct answer once you can. If you have the time, trying to work out what happened (kids work in mysterious ways) might help others as as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you already tried to troubleshoot with this help-guide?

> Step 1: Start the Bluetooth service.
>
> 1. Click Start, type services.msc and hit enter.
> 2. From the list of items, double click Bluetooth Support Service.
> 3. Change the startup type to Automatic and click Start button to start service.
> 4. Click Apply and then click ok.
>
> Step 2:  Uninstall and re-install the drivers for your Bluetooth
> device and then check for the issue.
>
> You may use the device manager to uninstall and reinstall the
> Bluetooth device drivers.
>
> Follow the steps to check the Bluetooth drivers in device manager:
>
> a. Click Start, then type ‘Device Manager’ without quotes in the
> search box. If you are prompted for an administrator password or for a
> confirmation, type the password, or click Allow.
>
> b. Locate the Bluetooth device by expanding the categories. c. Now you
> may right-click the listed drivers Bluetooth Device (Personal Area
> Network) and Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI), here you will get
> all the option to update or Install/uninstall drivers. Click on
> Uninstall.
>
> d. Check if at all there is an exclamation mark along the driver, it
> suggests issues with the driver installed.
>
> e. Restart the computer. This will let the computer automatically
> detect the device drivers on restart of the computer.

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/bluetooth-radio-device-is-not-available/3c42ffd3-bf31-41ef-ae48-3e72840f7f40

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1187135)